# Replace missing values in excel worksheet using openpyxl module

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I’m trying to replace cells in my Excel worksheet that contains hyphen “-“ with the average value between the above lying cell and the below lying cell. I’ll been trying to do this by looping through each row in column 3

```
 import math
 from openpyxl import load_workbook
 import openpyxl

 d_filename="Snow.xlsx"
 wb = load_workbook(d_filename)

 sheet_ranges=wb["PIT 1"]'


def interpolatrion_of_empty_cell():

for i in range(7,31):
    if i =="-":
        sheet_ranges.cell(row = i, column = 3).value = mean(i-1,i+1)
    else:
        sheet_ranges.cell(row = i, column = 3).value

wb.save(filename = d_filename)
```

is this just to easy to do or is it not possible with openpyxl?

cheers//
Smiffo

Comment: So what is your problem? You have some errors?

Comment: ooh sorry.... forgot the the most important part. I'll get no error messages, but the cells that contains hyphen don't get replaced with the avarage values. They remain as hyphen after the file is saved. if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason values are not replaced is that you use `i` to check if its equal to `-`. i is an index, not the value of a cell. Also to calculate the mean, you are using indices, not the values of top and below cells.

So you could solve this in following way:

```
def interpolatrion_of_empty_cell():
     for i in range(7,31):
          cell_value = sheet_ranges.cell(row=i, column=3).value
          if cell_value == "-":
               top_value = sheet_ranges.cell(row=i+1, column=3).value
               bottom_value = sheet_ranges.cell(row=i - 1, column=3).value
               sheet_ranges.cell(row=i, column=3).value = (float(top_value) + float(bottom_value))/2
```

Not that this may require tweaking, as it does not accout for cases where tob and bottom rows are `-`, not numbers, or just empty cells.

Comment: This would normally fix the problem but what if the upper and/or lower cells also contain `'-'`?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye So this is the tweaking I wrote about. You need to check for the values if they are numbers, if not make some default values, e.g., 0.